# Wait for Listener to finish the task and get result for another function [Android]

Tags: java, android, function

I want to get a file path from my file browser function, but my file browser function has listener, so if i call another function after this file explorer function, it become crash because the path is still empty, here's two function that i want to call :

```
public void openFileExplorer() {
    File mPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/");
    fileDialog = new FileDialog(this, mPath);
    fileDialog.addFileListener(new FileDialog.FileSelectedListener() {
        public void fileSelected(File file) {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "selected file " + file.toString());
            chosenFile = file.toString();
        }
    });
    fileDialog.showDialog();
}

private void generateMFCC(String path) {
   // btnBrowse.setText("Done");
    Log.d(getClass().getName(), ": Success");
    buffer = mRecorder.ReadWave(path);
    data = new float[buffer.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
        data[i] = (float) buffer[i];
    }
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    preProcess = new PreProcess(data, samplePerFreame, sampleRate);
    featureExtract = new FeatureExtract(preProcess.framedSignal, sampleRate, samplePerFreame);
    featureExtract.makeMfccFeatureVector();
    featureVector = featureExtract.getFeatureVector();
    double[][] fv = featureVector.getMfccFeature();

    for (int i = 0; i < fv.length; i++) {
        test = test + "{" + "\n";
        for (int j = 0; j < fv[i].length; j++) {
            test = test + Double.toString(fv[i][j]) + ", ";
        }
        test = test + "}" + "\n";
    }}
```

i call the function like this :

```
openFileExplorer();
generateMFCC(chosenFile);
```

but it always gives error before the file explorer dialog open

Comment: Please post your stacktrace so we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call generateMFCC from openFileExplorer only.

```
public void openFileExplorer() {
    File mPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/");
    fileDialog = new FileDialog(this, mPath);
    fileDialog.addFileListener(new FileDialog.FileSelectedListener() {
        public void fileSelected(File file) {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "selected file " + file.toString());
            chosenFile = file.toString();
generateMFCC(chosenFile);

        }
    });
    fileDialog.showDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void openFileExplorer() {
    File mPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/");
    fileDialog = new FileDialog(this, mPath);
    fileDialog.addFileListener(new FileDialog.FileSelectedListener() {
        public void fileSelected(File file) {
            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "selected file " + file.toString());
            chosenFile = file.toString();
// you should call the function here
generateMFCC(chosenFile);
        }
    });
    fileDialog.showDialog();
}
```

think that should solve your issue, right now `generateMFCC(chosenFile);` is called irrespective of file being chosen
*before file is selected